# How to prevent event listener getting called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

Added event listener on a HTML element which is **retrieved by className** in the render method of highcharts but that listener is getting called twice. Please check below code where click event gets called.

1. Added link on xAxis of highchart in xAxis label formatter.
   [image]
2. Added onClick handler in the render of highchart
   [image]

But somehow this handler is getting called twice. I have added below multiple solutions but it doesn't work.

Solutions:

1. Added `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` but didn't work.
2. Below **{once: true}** solution didn't work

   label.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   console.log('click event');
   }, {once: true});
3. Removed event listener still click function get called.

[image]

Can someone please provide solution to avoid event listener getting called twice.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `render` event can be fired multiple times which results in multiple event listeners added. From Highcharts API:

> **render**
>
> Fires after initial load of the chart (directly after the load event),
> and after each redraw (directly after the redraw event).

---

As a solution, you can use another way to add the event listeners. By using [custom-events](https://blacklabel.github.io/custom_events/) plugin or `on` method, a callback function will be fired only once.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        const xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
        const ticks = xAxis.ticks;

        xAxis.tickPositions.forEach(tickPos => {
          ticks[tickPos].label.on('click', () => {
            console.log('CLICK')
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uo8hc526/

**Docs:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#on

Comment: We can add a solution based on tickPositions when labels aren't custom. Here labels are added in formatter so this solution is not working

Comment: thanks for the API reference, looks like I can add onClick event in redraw event callback.

Comment: Hi @Learner, It doesn't matter in this case. As you can see in the example that I provided, `formatter` is also used.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass once in method options object this will remove the eventListener when it'll fire first time for eg

```
let btn = document.querySelector("button")
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("Logged");
}, { once: true });
```

Comment: Thanks @Abbas but as I mentioned this solution also not working in my case.